# Using Active Directory Membership Provider prompts with Windows Security popup then my login.aspx so I have to login twice

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a deployed application that is using the Active Directory Membership Provider in order to authenticate users to our domain on an extranet. The application is using the `.NET 3.5` framework. If you run the application locally it goes straight to the login page. But if you run the application from its deployed location on the server it first prompts with a Windows Security login prompt and after logging in, you are taken to the login page where you must login again.  Why is this?

Comment: How is IIS configured for authentication?

Comment: Hi Chester, and welcome to SO!  I have edited your question (just slightly) to make it a bit more clear for the users here.  Once again, welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web application seems to be configured to use Active Directory Authentication (and doesn't allow anonymous access).  Your users internally are already logged on to the domain and so IIS simply lets them past.

Your login.aspx page is protected by IIS so that you must be a member of the domain in order to even see the login.aspx page.  This is a configuration issue in IIS and has very little to do with asp.net or C#.

If you are using forms authentication, you should be able to allow anonymous authentication in IIS and handle authentication using Forms only.  However, this entirely depends on the web app and enabling anonymous access may inadvertently expose information you didn't intend to be publicly accessible.

Without knowing more about your application it's difficult to offer any more advice.  Good luck.

Comment: My application wasn't actually bypassing anything, it was forcing the user to login via a Windows Security popup and then again on my login page. I had both Windows and Forms authentication turned on in IIS 7.5 and having very little exposure to the Active Directory Membership Provider, I just assumed that turning on Anonymous would bypass all logins, but that is not the case. That actually worked. I am very grateful for your detailed response!